# Confusion on FlutterFire's FirebaseAuth.currentUser documentation

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

The `currentUser` getter in `firebase_auth.dart` is:

```dart
  /// Returns the current [User] if they are currently signed-in, or `null` if
  /// not.
  // 
  /// You should not use this getter to determine the users current state,
  /// instead use [authStateChanges], [idTokenChanges] or [userChanges] to
  /// subscribe to updates.
  User? get currentUser {
    if (_delegate.currentUser != null) {
      return User._(this, _delegate.currentUser!);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

I'm wondering if it really means to say "You should not use this getter to **poll** the users current state". If it really is bad practice to use this function to get the current state could someone please explain the reason for this? Is the `currentUser` not automatically updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `authStateChanges` in code where I need to respond to changes in authentication state, but I use `currentUser` in code that needs to know **now** who the current user is, or if there's a current user.

I'd recommend everyone to do the same, but we see users so often using `currentUser` everywhere in their code, and it then dealing with failures, where `authStateChanges` and a `StreamBuilder` would work beautifully, that I guess the authors of this documentation wanted to be overly explicit.

If you have better wording in mind, I'm sure the authors would love a PR. :)

Comment: Great thanks; this is what I was hoping it meant but I wasn't sure. I'll try to come up with something more clear for a PR.

Answer (score 0):

This is not current user **state**, this is **current user**.

The currentUser get method don't determine the **current user state**.

The state must be variable in nature.

If you want to be informed when user changed, you must listen authStateChanges to determine current user and user state.